# OR condition not working in xlst if

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:when test="person/id!=127 or 112" >
```

or condition is not working in the above example. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your syntax wrong, and it should be an `and`, not `or`. Try this:

```
<xsl:when test="person/id!=127 and person/id!=112" >
```

If you put an `or` there, your condition is going to be `true` no matter what the value of ID is, because no number can equal 127 and 112 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try
     <xsl:when test="person/id!=127 and person/id!=112">

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
 not(person/id= 127 or person/id = 112)
```

**Try to always avoid the `!=` XPath operator**, due to its unintuitive (and rarely useful) semantics when one or both of its arguments are node-sets 9or sequences in XPath 2.0).

**When you have a long list to compare against, this kind of expression may be more convenient and efficient**:

```
not(contains('|101|105|108|112|123|127|', concat('|', person/id, '|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an xslt developer and never used it before. However, It appears that test statement is missing. what should xslt parser do with 112? no condition is provided for it.